# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'script'

Tags: php, string, offset

I can't make it work, still I am getting

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'script'
>   PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'show_type'
>   PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'content_line1'

```
/**
    * makeFromRow
    ******************************************************/
    function makeFromRow($row="") {

        $status = new ItemStatus();

        $this->discount_id              = ($row["discount_id"])             ? $row["discount_id"]           : "";

        $this->entered                  = ($row["entered"])                 ? $row["entered"]               : ($this->entered               ? $this->entered                : "");
        $this->updated                  = ($row["updated"])                 ? $row["updated"]               : ($this->updated               ? $this->updated                : "");

        $this->id                       = ($row["id"])                      ? $row["id"]                    : ($this->id                    ? $this->id                     : 0);
        $this->account_id               = ($row["account_id"])              ? $row["account_id"]            : 0;
        $this->image_id                 = ($row["image_id"])                ? $row["image_id"]              : ($this->image_id              ? $this->image_id               : 0);
        $this->image_id1                = ($row["image_id1"])               ? $row["image_id1"]             : ($this->image_id1             ? $this->image_id1              : 0);
        $this->image_id2                = ($row["image_id2"])               ? $row["image_id2"]             : ($this->image_id2             ? $this->image_id2              : 0);
        $this->image_id3                = ($row["image_id3"])               ? $row["image_id3"]             : ($this->image_id3             ? $this->image_id3              : 0);
        $this->image_id4                = ($row["image_id4"])               ? $row["image_id4"]             : ($this->image_id4             ? $this->image_id4              : 0);
        $this->category_id              = ($row["category_id"])             ? $row["category_id"]           : 0;
        $this->renewal_date             = ($row["renewal_date"])            ? $row["renewal_date"]          : ($this->renewal_date          ? $this->renewal_date           : 0);
        $this->destination_url          = ($row["destination_url"])         ? $row["destination_url"]       : "";
        $this->display_url              = ($row["display_url"])             ? $row["display_url"]           : "";
        $this->destination_protocol     = ($row["destination_protocol"])    ? $row["destination_protocol"]  : "";
        $this->caption                  = ($row["caption"])                 ? $row["caption"]               : "";
        $this->caption1                 = ($row["caption1"])                ? $row["caption1"]              : "";
        $this->caption2                 = ($row["caption2"])                ? $row["caption2"]              : "";
        $this->caption3                 = ($row["caption3"])                ? $row["caption3"]              : "";
        $this->caption4                 = ($row["caption4"])                ? $row["caption4"]              : "";
        $this->status                   = ($row["status"])                  ? $row["status"]                : ($this->status                ? $this->status                 : $status->getDefaultStatus());
        $this->type                     = ($row["type"])                    ? $row["type"]                  : ($this->type                  ? $this->type                   : 0);
        $this->section                  = ($row["section"])                 ? $row["section"]               : ($this->section               ? $this->section                : "general");
        $this->target_window            = ($row["target_window"])           ? $row["target_window"]         : 2;
        $this->content_line1            = ($row["content_line1"])           ? $row["content_line1"]         : "";
        $this->content_line11           = ($row["content_line11"])          ? $row["content_line11"]        : "";
        $this->content_line12           = ($row["content_line12"])          ? $row["content_line12"]        : "";
        $this->content_line13           = ($row["content_line13"])          ? $row["content_line13"]        : "";
        $this->content_line14           = ($row["content_line14"])          ? $row["content_line14"]        : "";
        $this->content_line2            = ($row["content_line2"])           ? $row["content_line2"]         : "";
        $this->content_line21           = ($row["content_line21"])          ? $row["content_line21"]        : "";
        $this->content_line22           = ($row["content_line22"])          ? $row["content_line22"]        : "";
        $this->content_line23           = ($row["content_line23"])          ? $row["content_line23"]        : "";
        $this->content_line24           = ($row["content_line24"])          ? $row["content_line24"]        : "";
        $this->unpaid_impressions       = ($row["unpaid_impressions"])      ? $row["unpaid_impressions"]    : ($this->unpaid_impressions    ? $this->unpaid_impressions     : 0);
        $this->impressions              = ($row["impressions"])             ? $row["impressions"]           : ($this->impressions           ? $this->impressions            : 0);
        $this->unlimited_impressions    = ($row["unlimited_impressions"])   ? $row["unlimited_impressions"] : ($this->unlimited_impressions ? $this->unlimited_impressions  : "n");
        $this->expiration_setting       = ($row["expiration_setting"])      ? $row["expiration_setting"]    : 0;
        $this->show_type                = ($row["show_type"])               ? $row["show_type"]             : 0;
        $this->script                   = ($row["script"])                  ? $row["script"]                : "";

    }

    /**
    * Save
    ******************************************************/
```

Comment: It means `$row["script"]` is undefined. Instead of `($row["script"])`, do `empty($row["script"])` for your checks. Note that `0`, `NULL`, `[]`, etc count as "empty", so make sure to account for those in the case where those values are valid.

Comment: you mean this?       $this->script                   = empty($row["script"])                  ? $row["script"]                : "";

Comment: Yes. That's exactly it.

Comment: i checked out the error_log file, but still getting PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'script'

Comment: Then there's probably another array elsewhere in the file that doesn't have the key 'script' in there. CTRL + F and find all instances where you use `$someArray["script"]` and add an `empty()` check.

Comment: Thanks, i found this one:  $banner_content .= "<div style=\"width: {$each_banner["width"]}px; height: {$each_banner["height"]}px; overflow: auto;\">".$each_banner["script"]."</div>";     but where do i need to put the empty?

Comment: Change `$each_banner["script"]` to `(empty($each_banner["script"]) ? $each_banner["script"] : "")` if you want it to print out the div when empty, or wrap the whole `$banner_content .= ...` in an `if` statement if you don't.

Comment: I guess the problem is somewhere else, because i am getting PHP Warning: Illegal string offset in all rows, from discount_id to scrips(

Comment: i guess is something wrong with mysql_fletch_array  : if (is_numeric($var) && ($var)) {
    $dbObj = db_getDBObject();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Banner WHERE id = $var";
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($dbObj->query($sql));
    $this->makeFromRow($row);
   } else {
    $this->makeFromRow($var);
   }

  }

Comment: Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to return an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `isset` function always:

For example replaces all `$row[`:

```
...
$this->show_type = ($row["show_type"]) ? $row["show_type"]: 0;
...
```

to:

```
...
$this->show_type = (isset($row["show_type"])) ? $row["show_type"]: 0;
...
```